# Using Groovy for variable expansion in Java properties

Tags: java, groovy, properties-file, variable-expansion

I frequently use standard Java property files for configuring my Groovy applications. One feature I have been missing is the ability to use variables as part of the property value so they can be expand dynamically during use. I thought I could provide this functionality using the following design:

1. Use a special format to annotate the properties that should be expanded. I have chosen to enclose such templates in double exclamation marks (!!). These property values are essentially a template to be expanded with the local variables
2. Before using the properties in the application, use the groovy 'evaluate' method to expand application variables in the template
3. Re-assign the original property key to the new value before use

So, if I have a property file *config.properties* with properties like:

```
version=2.3
local_lib=!!${env['GROOVY_HOME']}/${configProps.getProperty('version')}/lib!!
```

The *local_lib* property will be expanded from the *GROOVY_HOME* environment variable and the *version* property value.

In my application, I have coded this as follows:

```groovy
//Load the environment variables and configuration file
env=System.getenv()
configFile=new File('config.properties')
configProps= new Properties()
configProps.load(configFile.newDataInputStream())

//Replace configuration property values with their expanded equivalent
configProps.each{
  //if a property value is a template we evaluate it
  if (it.value.startsWith('!!')){
    valTemplate=it.value.replace('!!','"')
    it.value=evaluate(valTemplate)
  }
}

 //then we use the expanded property values
```

This seems to work. When I do

```
println configProps
```

I see that the value is expanded and not null

However, the *getProperty* method for the expanded property returns null.

```
assert configProps.getProperty('local_lib')=='C:\\DEVTOOLS\\groovy-2.4.7/2.3/lib'
   |           |                       |
   |           null                    false
   [local_lib:C:\DEVTOOLS\groovy-2.4.7/2.3/lib, version:2.3]
```

What is causing this discrepancy? I would have expected to return the value shown in the property map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `local_lib` value looks like a `String`, but it isn't. It is a `GString`, only lazily coerced to `String` as needed (like when printing out the `configProps` map value).

Thus, a little known effect of `Properties.getProperty()` takes effect here. When the actual map value is not a String, `Properties.getProperty()` returns `null`.

So, in order to get the desired behavior, you need to coerce the `GString` to `String` before you store the value in the property map. Like so:

```
it.value=evaluate(valTemplate).toString()
```

or

```
it.value=evaluate(valTemplate) as String
```

Then you should see the desired results downstream.

Comment: Incidentally, I avoid using Properties.getProperty() and Properties.setProperty() in Groovy for precisely this reason. I prefer to use map syntax and semantics when working with Properties objects.

Comment: Oh indeed @BalRog coercing to String solves the problem. Thank you!