# Different results when setting/getting System properties with GStrings in Groovy

Tags: groovy, properties, maps

I'm perplexed by Groovy's behavior here.  I've run through the debugger some to try to determine where in the dynamic mixins these code paths may be getting crossed but wondered if anyone could set me straight here.

Basically, in setting a system property with a GString for a value, depending on how I set the property, the property is not always readable back via certain methods.

I have seen [Why Map does not work for GString in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141245/why-map-does-not-work-for-gstring-in-groovy) and [Why groovy does not see some values in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705492/why-groovy-does-not-see-some-values-in-dictionary) but my question specifically applies to map values so not sure those apply or not?

Snippet :

```
def tdollar='dollar'

System.setProperty('key1', 'value1')
System.setProperty('key2', "value2$tdollar")
// Replace the below with any property setting method other than
// the above with the same results
System.properties['key4']='value4'
System.properties['key5']="value5$tdollar"

println System.hasProperty('key1')
println System.hasProperty('key2')
println System.hasProperty('key4')
println System.hasProperty('key5')
println

println System.getProperty('key1')
println System.getProperty('key2')
println System.getProperty('key4')
println System.getProperty('key5')
println

println System.properties.keySet()
println

println System.properties['key1']
println System.properties['key2']
println System.properties['key4']
println System.properties['key5']
```

Output:

```
null
null
null
null

value1
value2dollar
value4
null

[java.runtime.name, sun.boot.library.path, java.vm.version, gopherProxySet, java.vm.vendor, java.vendor.url, path.separator, java.vm.name, file.encoding.pkg, user.country, sun.java.launcher, sun.os.patch.level, program.name, key5, key4, java.vm.specification.name, user.dir, key2, java.runtime.version, key1, java.awt.graphicsenv, java.endorsed.dirs, os.arch, java.io.tmpdir, line.separator, java.vm.specification.vendor, os.name, tools.jar, sun.jnu.encoding, script.name, java.library.path, java.specification.name, java.class.version, sun.management.compiler, os.version, user.home, user.timezone, java.awt.printerjob, file.encoding, java.specification.version, java.class.path, user.name, java.vm.specification.version, sun.java.command, java.home, sun.arch.data.model, user.language, java.specification.vendor, awt.toolkit, java.vm.info, java.version, java.ext.dirs, sun.boot.class.path, java.vendor, file.separator, java.vendor.url.bug, sun.io.unicode.encoding, sun.cpu.endian, groovy.starter.conf, groovy.home, sun.cpu.isalist]

value1
value2dollar
value4
value5dollar
```

Why, if I don't use `System.setProperty(key, value)` syntax, is the property not readable via `System.getProperty(key)`, but is still readable via any other method?

Given this behavior, is there a best practice documented regarding System properties in Groovy.

Writing this, I wonder if this is just a general map question.  Will test.

Comment: See this answer for insight into the strange behavior of java ```Properties``` objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038580/using-groovy-for-variable-expansion-in-java-properties/39043586#39043586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.setProperty('key2', "value2$tdollar")
```

When you operate using this above method, the second argument is implicitly cast to a String from a GString

```
System.properties['key5']="value5$tdollar"
```

this use the underlying **setProperties** method in the System class (not **setProperty**), and hence gets resolved differently, causing issues. The GString might not be getting cast correctly or not getting converted to a string before being sent to the underlying java class. If you change the value from a GString to a string like this:

```
System.properties['key5']="value5" + tdollar
```

the issue disappears

Comment: Or just coerce the ```GString``` value to a ```String``` value, like the following: ```System.properties['key5']="value5$tdollar" as String```